# Question about a proposition about free groups, generators and relations. Is it true or false that $N=\ker\phi$ holds? Michael Artin "Algebra 1st Ed."

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, relations, free-groups, finitely-generated

I am reading "Algebra 1st Edition" by Michael Artin.

I feel free groups, generators and relations are very difficult.

The following proposition is Proposition (8.3) on p.221 in this book.

> (8.3) Proposition. The elements $x^n,y^2,xyxy$ form a set of defining relations for the dihedral group.

> (8.2) $x^n=1,y^2=1,xyxy=1.$

> Proof of Proposition (8.3). We showed in Chapter 5 (3.6) that $D_n$ is generated by elements $x,y$ which satisfy (8.2). Therefor there is a surjective map $\phi:F\to D_n$ from the free group on $x,y$ to $D_n$, and $R=\{x^n,y^2,xyxy\}$ is contained in $\ker\phi$. Let $N$ be the smallest normal subgroup of $F$ containing $R$. Then since $\ker\phi$ is a normal subgroup which contains $R,N\subset\ker\phi$. The mapping property of quotients gives us a homomorphism $\overline{\phi}:F/N\to D_n$. If we show that $\overline{\phi}$ is bijective, the proposition will be proved.
> Note that since $\phi$ is surjective, $\overline{\phi}$ is too. Also, in $F/N$ the relations $\overline{x}^n=1,\overline{y}^2=1$, and $\overline{x}\overline{y}\overline{x}\overline{y}=1$ hold. Using them, we can put any word in $\overline{x},\overline{y}$ into the form $\overline{x}^i\overline{y}^j$, with $0\leq i\leq n-1$ and $0\leq j\leq 1$. This shows that $F/N$ has at most $2n$ elements. Since $|D_n|=2n$, it follows that $\overline{\phi}$ is bijective, as required.

My question is about $\ker\phi$.
$N\subset\ker\phi$ holds.
Is it true or false that $N=\ker\phi$ holds?
If $N\subsetneq\ker\phi$, please give me an element $\overline{a}$ such that $\overline{a}\notin N$ but $\overline{a}\in\ker\phi$.

Comment: Since the argument proves that $\overline{\varphi}$ is bijective, and $\varphi=\overline{\varphi}\circ\pi$, where $\pi$ is the projection onto $F/N$, then of course the kernel is exactly $N$. What is the problem?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you very much for your answer!